# Can someone explain why this regular expression matches differently with different regex flavors?

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

The text is:

```
Here is some text!
```

The regular expression (looking for a single match) is:

```
Here is (\w+\s?)+
```

In .NET there is one match: `Here is some text`

...but in javascript there are two: `Here is some text` and `text`.

Why are there two matches in js and only one in .NET?

Comment: In .NET have you tried referencing the capture group `$1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses in regular expressions create a capturing group.  In js what you are seeing is the complete match and the group match, in .NET you are only seeing the complete match (although you should be able to access the group as well).

If you don't want to capture what you have inside of the parentheses use this regular expression instead:

`Here is (?:\w+\s?)+`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same as what .Net give you as matches, in js do :

```
var regex = new RegExp("Here is (\\w+\\s?)+", "g");

var txt = "Here is some text!";
while (match = regex.exec(txt)) {
  window.alert(match[0]);
}
```

It should alert only once in your case with what you expect. each match array contain the match at position 0 and then all the capture groups but you don't seem to need them.